Im trying to implement a google sign-in for my web app, does it cost anything?
Im trying to implement google sign-in for my web app, Im wondering if it has any cost or something.
My web app has its own authentication/authorization, I just need the google sign in to get the user name and email then create a session with my web app.
So far as Im searching,I see the Google Identity Platform which the google sign-in uses.
They have their tier 1 and tier 2. Tier 2 uses Open ID Connect, which I think most websites use for google sign in?


So like, if I use external google sign in, it will automatically fall in Tier 2 which uses OIDC, then I have to pay 0.015 per MAU exceeding 50?
That's quite expensive actually.


So like, if I use external google sign in, it will automatically fall in Tier 2 which uses OIDC, then I have to pay 0.015 per MAU exceeding 50?

Yes, if you are using the OIDC and indeed uses OpenID Connect (OIDC). The pricing you mentioned is correct, with a charge of $0.015 per monthly active user (MAU) exceeding 50.
For small applications, this might not be a significant cost, but it can add up as your user base grows. You could also choose other OIDC  provider like Azure Extra ID or else. It depends on your application requirement.
